# Passing arguments to ProcessStartInfo class

Tags: c#, .net, processstartinfo, redirectstandardoutput

i want to call the command prompt command using Process.Start and then using StandardOutput i want to read using StreamReader in my application but when i run the below program, in the MessageBox i just find the path till Debug, my command which i have stated in arguments does not exexutes.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "net view");
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;    

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();

            using(StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
```

here my net view command never executes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run a command with `cmd` you have to specify the `/c` argument too:

```
new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c net view");
```

In this case, however, you don't need `cmd` at all. `net` is a native program and can be executed as is, without a shell:

```
new ProcessStartInfo("net", "view");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember also to intercept the StandardErrorOutput or will see nothing:

```cs
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("net", "view");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    string message;

    using (var reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        message = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var reader = process.StandardError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```